# Paypal: Issue verifying the signature of secure order - but encryption works

Tags: encryption, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I developed a cart_upload system which went online at the beginning of this year. After a few months, the certificates expired and were exchanged. This exchange worked well on the live system (I'm so happy :-) ) but not in the sandbox. Before exchanging the certs everything worked, on both, sandbox and live system.

When I click my button (to sandbox.paypal.com), it says

**There was a problem verifying the signature of your secure order. Please contact your merchant.**

Before, there were other error messages. They concerned the encryption. Paypal could not decrypt my data. I solved them all. But I can't solve this error here, because I do not find any usefull information about that.

- certificate ID is correct
- Paypal public certificate is on my server
- Certificates are generated using openssl. This worked fine on the live system.

Is it possible that Paypal needs to enter certain data into the public cert? Which data do I have to insert when using the sandbox? I already tried to enter the data of my sandbox account but it didn't help. Is something locked because I've exchanged certificated too often?

Has anyone an idea why this error occurs?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems paypal changed something in their setup. I created to fresh sandbox accounts (buyer and seller). Then, I wanted to log in to my sandbox. Went to developer.paypal.com > Dashboard > Accounts. Created the accounts. Then clicked on "Enter Sandbox site". It opens a new tab sandbox.paypal.com **which then forwards to paypal.com**????

Comment: Here, finally the solution: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/739/kw/There%20was%20a%20problem%20verifying%20the%20signature%20of%20your%20secure%20order.%20Please%20contact%20your%20merchant. Something was wrong with my certs. Don't know why it does not say encryption failed. Forwarding to live paypal seems to be a session problem, in another browser it worked.